# What causes the error "Unable to find the private GraphQL API for this domain."?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

A lambda function deployed to private subnet attempting to access an AppSync GraphQL API  through an appsync VPC endpoint fails with the error:

"Unable to find the private GraphQL API for this domain."

As of posting this question, that phrase doesn't appear in Google search results.

Answer (score 2):

In mid-2023, AWS introduced a feature called [Private APIs on AWS Appsync](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/introducing-private-apis-on-aws-appsync/).  This allows creating APIs that are only accessible from within a VPC through a VPC endpoint (AWS PrivateLink).

The above error resulted from trying to use an appsync VPC endpoint to access a **public** AppSync API.  It seems that this is not possible through a VPC endpoint.  Instead, resources within the subnet must access public AppSync APIs through a NAT gateway.